# Are constant random variables independent?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Is the following solution correct?

[image]

Are constant random variables ***really*** not independent?

Comment: Where is this from? Also, can you explain why you believe that $E(X|\mathcal{G})=0.5$?

Comment: Sorry, you're correct $E(X|\mathcal{G}) = 0$, I confused it with another distribution.

Comment: http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/suppl/10.1142/6300/suppl_file/6300-solutionsmanual_free.pdf, p. 60

Comment: that looks pretty weird to me, I must say.

Comment: Since this "solution" to exercise 13.4.6 is obviously bogus, one may want to cite the recommendation from the preface of the manual, by Rosenthal: "Of course, this solutions manual may well contain errors, perhaps significant ones. If you find some, then please e-mail me and I will try to correct them promptly." The authors repeat the very same mistake in their "solution" to exercise 13.4.10. The "solution" to 13.4.4 is faulty as well (confusing real numbers $x$ with a random variable $X$). All in all, these are 3 bogus "solutions" from 6 given in the manual for Chapter 13.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constant random variables are always independent. Why? Let $R$ and $S$ be constant random variables. For sets $A$ and $B$, we have
$$P(R\in A,S\in B) = \boldsymbol{1}_{\{R\in A,S\in B\}} = \boldsymbol{1}_{\{R\in A\}}\boldsymbol{1}_{\{S\in B\}}=P(R\in A)P(S\in B).$$

In the first equality, I consider the probability $P(R\in A, S\in B)$. Since $R$ and $S$ are constants, either $R$ is in the set $A$, or it is not, and likewise for $S$. This means that either it is definitely true that $R\in A$ and $S\in B$, in which case the probability is one (it is a sure event, regardless of which $\omega$ we consider), and otherwise it is not true, in which case the probability is $0$. I can express this as an indicator function on the event $\{R\in A\}\cap \{S\in B\}$.

For the second equality, I use that for any sets $C$ and $D$, it is true that

$\boldsymbol{1}_{C\cap D} = \boldsymbol{1}_C\boldsymbol{1}_D.$

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the second step. To me, constant random variables are independent, because they generate the $\sigma$-algebra $\{\emptyset, \Omega\}$, which is independent to itself.

Comment: Ah, I used the old-fashioned definition of independence, which says that two random variables $X$ and $Y$ are indepedendent, if $P(X\in A\cup Y\in B) = P(X\in A)P(Y\in B)$ for all measurable sets $A$ and $B$. I will try to elaborate on my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I obviously meant $\cap$ instead of $\cup$ in my comment above. And I meant "independent" instead of "indepedendent"...